# How to fix ValueError: Field `active` does not exist in odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-12

I have a view which inherits from view employee form, with fields from a model I created, but whenever I try to upgrade the module it shows me the ValueError: Field `active` does not exist error.

Here is the view from which I inherited the employee form.

```xml
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="training_log_employee_form_inherit">
        <field name="name">training.log.employee.form.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">training.log.emp</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
           <xpath expr="//notebook" position="inside">
              <page string="Training Log">
                <field name="training_log_line">
                  <form>
                    <group string="Employee Training">
                      <field name="date"/>
                      <field name="course"/>
                      <field name="type_list"/>
                      <field name="completion_status"/>
                    </group>
                  </form>
                    <tree editable="bottom">
                      <field name="date"/>
                      <field name='course'/>
                      <field name="type_list"/>
                      <field name="completion_status"/>
                    </tree>
                  </field>       
                </page>

            </xpath>

        </field>
      </record>
```

This is the training.log.emp model

```py
class TrainingLog(models.Model):
    _name = 'training.log.emp'

    hr_employee = fields.Many2one('hr.employee')
    date = fields.Date()
    course = fields.Char()
    type_list = fields.Many2one('Type', 'hr.training.log')
    completion_status = fields.Selection([
        ('done', 'Done'),
        ('in_view', 'In View'),
        ])
```

ValueError: Field `active` does not exist

Error context:
View `training_log_employee_form_inherit`
[view_id: 373, xml_id: n/a, model: training.log.emp, parent_id: 302]

Comment: delete your db and create a new one

Comment: Done that still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're creating the view for the right model? I would say it has to be `hr.employee` and not `training.log.emp`, because you're also inheriting a `hr.employee` view and you just want to show a one2many field on Employees with relation to your new model `training.log.emp`.

Comment: I didn't know that odoo allow this, inherit a view of another model!! You are right he should write `<field name="model">hr.employee</field>`

Comment: It is possible when `_inherits` is involved like for product templates and variants.

Comment: Thank you I missed that apparntly