# Field `field_x` does not exist (Odoo 13)

Tags: python, odoo

I created 2 models in different modules.I install the first module (classA)... but when trying to install the second one , I got this error :

```
File "/opt/odoo13/community/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 614, in raise_view_error
    raise ValueError(message)
ValueError: Field `field_ids` does not exist

Error context:
View `calendar_extend_form`
[view_id: 583, xml_id: n/a, model: calendar.event, parent_id: 378]
```

//py

```
 (module1)
    class A(models.Model):
        _inherit = 'calendar.event'

    field_ids = fields.Many2many('res.partner', 'calendar_event_present_ids', 'calendar_id', 'present_id')
    field_x = fields.Html(string='x')

(module2)
class B(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'calendar.event'
```

//xml

```
 <record id="calendar_extend_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">calendar_extend_form</field>
            <field name="model">calendar.event</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="module1.calendar_extend_view_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath....
                       <field name="field_ids" widget="many2manyattendee"/>
                       <field name="field_x"/>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Any help please ?
Thanks.

Comment: please see this question, it can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58765016/how-to-fix-valueerror-field-active-does-not-exist-in-odoo

Comment: Does module2 depend on module1? I mean it does, but does that reflect in the module2 Manifest file?

Comment: Add module1 name in module2 minifest depends file like 'depends': ['base','module1']